# Multiprocessing in python accessing the same array

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, covariance

I have a very large array that I need to run some operations on which takes a lot of time so I'm trying to implement multiprocessing, however I don't see any speed up (even runs a few percent slower than single core). Could the reason be that each process locks to array while it computes? As you can see below I only need to read the array and it should be left unmodified when the worker is finsihed.

How should I implement this correctly?

The operation I need to perform is to calculate the covariance between two large vectors for different shifts of one of the vectors, if you can point out a better solution than mine below, please feel free to do so. Typical size of the vectors is 10 million elements, 101 different shifts and repeating that 1 000 times.

Thank you,
Andreas

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector
    def __call__(self, x):
        return np.cov(self.vector[0],np.roll(self.vector[1],x))[0,1]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(8) # on 8 processors  
    workers = Worker([np.random.normal(size=10000000),np.random.normal(size=10000000)])
    data_inputs = np.random.randint(10, size=50)
    data_outputs = pool.map(workers, data_inputs) 
    print data_outputs
```

Comment: See this: [ http://folk.uio.no/sturlamo/python/multiprocessing-tutorial.pdf ]. It shows how to use numpy arrays and multiprocessing together.

Comment: If the processing time is short, then the overall time may be dominated by setting up the subprocesses (especially on windows). How long does your single-process version take?

Comment: @mdurant: Nope, the workload is quite significant. Is it of order of seconds.